# Make body behave like a button when I click anywhere and save

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a text area, button to save the text that is type inside the text area and some other stuff on the page.

I want to click outside of the body and save the text that I type inside the text area; my body should act as button.

My problem is it does save the information but it affects everything that I have on my page e.g. wherever I click, it saves and I want it not to save when I click some other button - it should focus only outside the element.

What should I do to focus only outside the element because I even try function called stopPropagation.

```js
var text_a = document.getElementById("myTextarea");
var btn_saveComment = document.getElementById("submit2");

function saveComments() {
  text_a.style.display = "block";
  $("#comment").text($(text_a).val());
  var g = document.getElementById("checks5");
  g.checked = true;
  g.disabled = false;
  $("#checks5").css({
    backgroundColor: "#C40929"
  })
}

document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  text_a.style.display = "block";
  $("#comment").text($(text_a).val());
  var g = document.getElementById("checks5");
  g.checked = true;
  g.disabled = false;
  $("#checks5").css({
    backgroundColor: "#C40929"
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="checkbox" class="check_ticks" id="checks5">
  <label for="checks5"></label>
</div>

<p id="comment" class="text_info"></p>
<textarea id="myTextarea" rows="5" cols="30" class="myText"></textarea>
<button class="dropbtn" id="submit2" onclick="saveComments()">Save Comment</button>
```

Comment: It is not clear what the code does NOT do. Please detail the steps to recreate and let us know what is expected behaviour

Comment: do you mean you want to save the comments only when you exit the text area (i.e. `onBlur`)?

Comment: yes i want to do that

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add `onBlur` attribute to the text area.  Like this:

```
<textarea id="myTextarea" rows="5" cols="30" onblur="saveComments()" class="myText"></textarea>
```

**See demo below:**

```js
var text_a = document.getElementById("myTextarea");
var btn_saveComment = document.getElementById("submit2");

function saveComments() {
  console.log('saving...');
  text_a.style.display = "block";
  $("#comment").text($(text_a).val());
  var g = document.getElementById("checks5");
  g.checked = true;
  g.disabled = false;
  $("#checks5").css({
    backgroundColor: "#C40929"
  });
  console.log('saved');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="checkbox" class="check_ticks" id="checks5">
  <label for="checks5"></label>
</div>

<p id="comment" class="text_info"></p>
<textarea id="myTextarea" rows="5" cols="30" onblur="saveComments()" class="myText"></textarea>
<button class="dropbtn" id="submit2" onclick="saveComments()">Save Comment</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much I appreciate your effort.

Comment: @Justice don't forget to upvote helpful answers and select one as the best answer when done

Answer (score 0):

Using simple vanilla Javascript you can use the `event` to aid the process of using the document Body to work as the button in the original code by inspecting the `event.target` and `event.currentTarget` properties. When the event listener is bound to the body ( as below ) the currentTarget is the body element itself rather than any child element so that allows you to process the click on that itself quite easily.

( css to make this easier to observe within the snippet )

```js
const d=document;

d.body.addEventListener('click',e=>{

  let oText=d.querySelector('textarea#myTextarea');
  
  if( e.target==e.currentTarget && oText.value!='' ){
    let oPara=d.querySelector('p#comment');
        oPara.textContent=oText.value;
        
    let oChk=d.querySelector('input#checks5'); 
        oChk.checked=true;
        oChk.disabled=false;
        oChk.style.backgroundColor="#C40929"
  }
})
```

```css
body{
  height:100vh;
  width:100%;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="checkbox" class="check_ticks" id="checks5">
  <label for="checks5"></label>
</div>

<p id="comment" class="text_info"></p>
<textarea id="myTextarea" rows="5" cols="30" class="myText"></textarea>
```